Touchpad doesn't work on 24.04 Huawei Matebook
I bought new huawei matebook x pro (2024 model) and click events works but the cursor never move.
I found a lot of posts regarding similar issues but none of the solutions work for me. I've tried libinput, synaptics, changing boot parameters, disabling and enabling psmouse and i2c kernel module etc. I also checked different kernels and distributions. Interestingly, evtest correctly reads the coordinates:
Event: time 1717688605.289478, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1717688605.296465, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 1324
Event: time 1717688605.296465, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 54 (ABS_MT_POSITION_Y), value 803
Event: time 1717688605.296465, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1324
Event: time 1717688605.296465, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 803
Event: time 1717688605.296465, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 444000
Event: time 1717688605.296465, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1717688605.303654, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 1325
Event: time 1717688605.303654, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1325
Event: time 1717688605.303654, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 451000
Event: time 1717688605.303654, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1717688605.310486, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 53 (ABS_MT_POSITION_X), value 1327
Event: time 1717688605.310486, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 1327
Event: time 1717688605.310486, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 5 (MSC_TIMESTAMP), value 458000

xinput looks ok:
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ICNT9288:00 7F7F:9288                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver System Control      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Huawei WMI hotkeys                        id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control    id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]


EDIT:
My xorg config:
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad only"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "synaptics"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
    Option "AccelSpeed" "1"
EndSection

dmesg output:
[    2.383747] input: GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-GXTP7863:00/0018:27C6:01E0.0001/input/input4
[    2.449802] input: GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-0/i2c-GXTP7863:00/0018:27C6:01E0.0001/input/input8

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve such issue?

Set this at /usr/share/libinput/50-system-huawei.quirks:
# 2024 model requires ModelPressurePad=1
[Huawei MateBook X Pro 2024 Touchpad]
MatchName=GXTP7863:00 27C6:01E0 Touchpad
MatchUdevType=touchpad
MatchDMIModalias=dmi:*svnHUAWEI:*pnVGHH-XX*
AttrEventCode=-BTN_RIGHT
ModelPressurePad=1

